# Casperjs and Failed to save screenshot with captureSelector

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I have such code :

```
  casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    this.echo('Opening at ' + width);
    //give some time for the page to load
    casper.waitFor(function check() {
      return this.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelectorAll('#browse-packshots').length > 0;
      });
    }, function then() {
      //set the viewport to the desired height and width
      this.viewport(width, height);
      //Set up two vars, one for the fullpage save, one for the actual viewport save
      var FPfilename = saveDir + '/fullpage-' + width + ".png",
          ACfilename = saveDir + '/' + width + '-' + height + ".png";

      //Capture selector captures the whole body
      this.captureSelector(FPfilename, 'body');
      //capture snaps a defined selection of the page
      this.capture(ACfilename,{top: 0,left: 0,width: width, height: height});
      this.echo('snapshot taken');
    },function timeout() {
      this.echo("Too long . No screenshot taken").exit();
    },10000);
  })
```

Casper version is 1.0.4 on Mac. When I want to use captureSelector I'm getting

```
[error] [phantom] Failed to save screenshot to fullpage-1440.png;
                  please check permissions...
```

With capture there is no problem. I event try with sudo but with no effect.

Comment: You tried executing the casperjs script as sudo? you may have to sudo phantomjs your_casper_script.js

Comment: Yes I have done this and this is in description of problem. Strange that when I doing this with capture it working without problem with permission and this is the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found answer . I change one stuff in code:

```
this.captureSelector(FPfilename, 'html');
```

Have not idea why it wasn't working.

Comment: I have the same/similar issue.  If I use a specific selector, I get this problem.  But if I use a broader selector (like 'body' or 'html'), it works fine.  I also haven't found out why it happens (doesn't happen to all selectors), but if I do, I'll come back and let you know!