# failed to save screenshot to a location in casperjs (windows7 64 bit)

Tags: phantomjs, windows-7-x64, casperjs

When trying to capture a screenshot and save it in casperjs, it throws the following error

[error] [phantom] Failed to save screenshot to a local directory. please check permissions

Tried lot of ways like

- saving it to other locations like public directory
- changing the permissions of the local directory.
- running the process as an administrator.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit machine.

Already gone through this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070925/casperjs-and-failed-to-save-screenshot-with-captureselector)

Comment: Please let me know when you get a solution. I too face the same problem!

Comment: did you tried to save the file in the same folder ?

Comment: Can you provide some code for review and testing?

Comment: that is interesting try to save in the same directory just out of curiosity, I've never tried to save images elsewhere and I've never run into a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. and from what i found ,  it's also possible getting this error when the screenshot retrieved  from a url/link which has no response body
  (see also [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/IoiYbjAYIzk))

So I solved that through something like that:

```
 ...

 if (this.exists("body")) {   // this refer to the casper object
     this.capture(myTrgFile);
}
```

please note that the request body and the tag body are two different things. I used the tag ("body") in my example only because it usually appears when requesting an html page. (the tag body is locate in the request body)

hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue recently and I solved it by allowing multiple ssl protocols using the following:

```
casperjs --ssl-protocol=any myscript.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue. save name also can make this problem.
i used to save file name  as get.Title() 
some of site name didn't proper as file name

```
 var title = this.getTitle();
       this.echo(title);
        var filename = i + '_' + title + '.png';
```

-->   `var filename = i + '_.png';`

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error running Casperjs on Windows. For me closing and reopen the command prompt makes the script work again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get that error message if you haven't specified a file extension. There is no default image extension, so you have to specify:

```
// this won't work
this.captureSelector("./images/filename", "html");

// this WILL work
this.captureSelector("./images/filename.png", "html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a file with the same name already exists, and is opened by a program (image viewer) so casperjs/phantomjs can't delete it before rewriting.